# Objective C: TabBarController and TableViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

i want a TabelView-Navigation and permanently a TabBar at the bottom .

I pushed the TabBarController. It contains a list of Controllers (ViewController, ... and the TableViewController)
But if i navigate down in the TableView the TabBar moves to the left outside the window (like the old Table).

How can i use the TabBarController without losing him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UITabBarController needs to be the root view controller.  It sounds like you are pushing a UITabBarController onto the stack of a UINavigationController.  What you want to do is make the UINavigationController one of the view controllers managed by the tab bar controller.

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

1. Create the Tab Bar Controller and set it as your rootController.

   ```
   //You will not have three tabs and you need three view controllers//
   ```
2. Set your First View controller as a Navigation View controller.

   ```
   // You will now have the Navigation bar at the top//
   ```
3. Create a new file which is a subclass of the UITableViewController.

   ```
   // set this as your delegate and datasource for your table view controller methods//
   // pull a table view controller inside the Navigation View Controller as mentioned in (2) & you will have a tableview and navigation view in FirstViewController. Similarly work with the other two tabs
   ```

If you have any more doubts; please watch this tutorial on how to do all of these.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw

Comment: this is an exact duplicate of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255002/uibarbutton-wont-show-up-on-table-view-within-tab-controller/6255948#6255948). Excessive duplication raises flags by other users and can be viewed as spam. You should tailor your answers to fit the question rather than posting "boilerplate" answers. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry man. Apologies. Same question. I had just typed the answer for that one and then I came across this immediately. Will not happen again.