# UIBarButton won't show up on Table View within Tab Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem, uitabcontroller

noob question regarding ios development.

In a previous project, I have a UITableViewController, to which I am adding a button in the viewDidLoad method, like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                           target:self
                           action:@selector(addMeasurement:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
[button release];
```

This works great.

I now have another application in which I am trying to do the same thing, except now I have a UITabBarControllerDelegate at the top (the default that comes along with "Tab Bar Application"), whose first view is the UITableViewController.

The First View has no nib as it's just a table. I am trying to do the same thing with the same code, trying to add a button in the viewDidLoad method, but it's not working.

So in the firstViewController (which is a UITableViewController) I am adding the above code to the viewDidLoad method, with no success.

It is showing data in the table, however (from a managedObjectContext). I've also tried putting the code in the "initWithStyle" method of the firstViewController but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas? Clearly I'm not understanding something.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you add a button on the Delegate ? Add the button to the First View.

Comment: I think this is what I'm doing. I'm adding it to FirstViewController (which is a UITableViewController). Or is that incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this.

1. Create the Tab Bar Controller and set it as your rootController.

   ```
   //You will not have three tabs and you need three view controllers//
   ```
2. Set your First View controller as a Navigation View controller.

   ```
   // You will now have the Navigation bar at the top//
   ```
3. Create a new file which is a subclass of the UITableViewController.

   ```
   // set this as your delegate and datasource for your table view controller methods//
   // pull a table view controller inside the Navigation View Controller as mentioned in (2) & you will have a tableview and navigation view in FirstViewController. Similarly work with the other two tabs
   ```

If you have any more doubts; please watch this tutorial on how to do all of these.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw

Answer (score 2):

If i'm not mistaken you need to have your UITableViewController within a UINavigationController in order to show UIBarButtonItems.